# Any Acrhive extracting program (winzip or winrar) from where i can copy file

Tags: archiving, winrar

I use winrar for extracting the files.
BUt i find one thing very annoying e,g i double click on the acthive to view the contents

then if i want to copy one file on desktop i can't do that.

there is no right click `copy` option in the menu.

There is extract option but then i have to choose the path and thats time consuming.

Is there any way around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always drag-and-drop the file to wherever you want it.

Is that not enough?

Comment: thanks buddy , i didn't thought about drag and drop

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend checking out [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/). It's free, and does most archive types.  I just double-checked, and I can drag one file out of a RAR to my desktop, and there is a right-click->Copy To... option as well.

I'm kind of surprised WinRAR doesn't let you do it, but WinRAR is a little dated these days (IMO - I used to use it).